# CyanogenMod browser displays only a white screen

Tags: cyanogenmod, browser

I just installed CyanogenMod (11-M12) on my Galaxy S3 I9300. Now after some days, web browser only displays a white screen, not page content, not address bar, only a full screen white page (only taskbar on top).

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache/recent apps? Try going to settings->apps->browser->clear cache